# Ruby on Rails: How do I run a Cucumber task inside a rake file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, I have this

Rake::Task['FEATURE=features/Authentication.feature cucumber'].invoke

but id doesn't work.. says

```
Don't know how to build task 'FEATURE=features/Authentication.feature cucumber'
```

but when I do

```
rake FEATURE=features/Authentication.feature cucumber
```

that works... =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new rake file (lib/tasks):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

namespace :cucumber do

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:authentication2) do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = "features/Authentication.feature"
end


Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:preview_all) do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = "features/Preview.feature features/PreviewButton.feature"
end

end
```